# Button with varying localized title with auto layout

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode6, autolayout, nsbutton

I am looking into taking the plunge and use Auto Layout on an existing app. The interface has a button on the main window. The button changes its title depending on the state of the app. I plan to localize the app.

Since Auto Layout does not know (in the NIB) the length of the various titles that the button will adopt, how can I guarantee that the button will, for each localization, be sized in such a way that it will fit the longest-length title in each localization?

What is the right way to accomplish this? Many thanks.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the layout here.

Comment: I haven't implemented the Auto Layout constraints as of yet. Once I do, if I still need help, I will make sure to post screenshots of the layout.

Comment: Sure wagill. Will help you in Auto Layout when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change much. You just add the alignment constraints whatever you added. Now give it width and height constraints and make them greater than equals to the minimum value you wanted. See this.

[image]

I have added center horizontal and vertical for alignment. This you can change to any. Now the width is here greater than equals to 42.0 and the height is greater than equals to 21.0 . Now if you just change the text of the button then it will increase its height and width according to that. You just need to call this line just after changing the text.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Now you may have question that you want to limit the width and then increase height. Here is the solution. You give it width less than equals to max width and it will not increase the width more than that. See here.

[image]

Here my max width is 200.0. But make sure that if you are adding those layout constraints in iOS and it is a UILabel then than **Lines** is 0 and if it is a UIButton then the **Line Break** is **Word Wrap** or **Character Wrap**, but in OS X increasing height of NSButton depends on your button type.

Comment: Thank you, Mahesh, for your thorough reply. From your answer I am inferring that the button will be resized realtime as I programmatically change the button's title during runtime. Now I am curious, if the controls on the window are such that they abut each other horizontally (and in my interface they do), will the window also resize itself to fit the expanded button size? Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Welcome.... And if you need to resize the window according to the text of the control then you just need to remove resizing constraints of the window and assign leading, trailing, top and bottom according to your requirement from the control to its parent view whichever you want to resize, may be a window or maybe anything and it will be also resized.

Answer (score 1):

If you have given constraints to your button, just remove it's fixed width constraint, button will automatically fit as per text's width.

Comment: Try adding a sample code, this will help the user understand the solution better.

Comment: Thanks for showing the way @Rudra, i'll take care about this.